# How to fix 'Docker command failed with exit code 125' when using visual studio

Tags: docker

I am using visual studio 2019 to build .NET CORE web api.
When i build the application with docker via VS2019, i am getting the error:
"Docker command failed with exit code 125".

Any idea what is the cause?
This is the Output:

```
1>d2c0ee48dbf44507b3dee44a17ab8b8186fe4ec59c283af834191e8f3c902f1a
1>C:\Users\97254\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.9.5\build\Container.targets(196,5): error CTC1015: Docker command failed with exit code 125.
1>C:\Users\97254\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.9.5\build\Container.targets(196,5): error CTC1015: docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem d2c0ee48dbf44507b3dee44a17ab8b8186fe4ec59c283af834191e8f3c902f1a: The request is not supported.
1>C:\Users\97254\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.9.5\build\Container.targets(196,5): error CTC1015: (extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"d2c0ee48dbf44507b3dee44a17ab8b8186fe4ec59c283af834191e8f3c902f1a","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\d2c0ee48dbf44507b3dee44a17ab8b8186fe4ec59c283af834191e8f3c902f1a","Layers":[{"ID":"51d2ce01-5190-5398-8d36-73a41302a60e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\47c9023ce74aa96d2e5002cdf0f7e354f5de55b217e08498dda14e1be5d6998f"},{"ID":"c6ab7d12-aab5-5873-9f2e-0ec11613a58d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\035fac58f721cc9c158ef24fdb84a7e74eb4eea2cf29421a3744241cc62eabe7"},{"ID":"cdf32ccb-53d2-56ad-8b1d-9dfa6ae076d7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7ac67c0c7c4a6dfc2c0becbc948078b48873f003c49f16c1d0be0d69b179d3b3"},{"ID":"4c8a0736-dba8-5fde-8cc0-56aa33e0149d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\43ad281ee856dabf07411276e5774b386bd37aee8b3099c3b7faa1d314a7013e"},{"ID":"af791769-1fd1-5170-b6e4-2245156a8f6f","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\878625f6c364e37ff07532212a6979f096de46d9eb455c964366ecd5a9c03ba9"},{"ID":"082795f2-b562-5088-a34f-91d16d7e5c36","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\4dbda25002ed56956709c11b4cc902083e712fc8a862b2b62970e839ec2bffec"},{"ID":"e409f795-d9cf-539a-ac95-dbedc3506ccb","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7e2f83b59544b3cf2e553cdd9d94dd27a4684360c23f44d93a2b39e5dd0301cb"},{"ID":"a5fdd7a2-0ea0-553a-9c1e-976a729321e3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\27f0f73d07810d0877a35fc1215e5336e6034eba1c08974f2f308796c9a32890"},{"ID":"b0175521-e8e7-55e8-97a8-77d96d2bb78a","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\03bb0041548802485ca5cc3a0475fde8905f048e50eb6b43413b1796b34773ad"},{"ID":"85e06fce-32e5-5cb6-8678-a4750186c146","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8f5d06ad16da8edecc28898e8cda1ce15e4087e16e1b9a5d2d7a4d10a2c55398"}],"HostName":"d2c0ee48dbf4","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\\users\\97254\\onecoremsvsmon\\16.3.0039.0","ContainerPath":"c:\\remote_debugger","ReadOnly":true,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"c:\\cheggtest\\qfetcherapi","ContainerPath":"c:\\app","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"c:\\cheggtest","ContainerPath":"c:\\src","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"c:\\users\\97254\\.nuget\\packages","ContainerPath":"c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages2","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"c:\\program files\\dotnet\\sdk\\nugetfallbackfolder","ContainerPath":"c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["766EA888-2541-4D88-B330-EBD3ECA2FF64"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8f5d06ad16da8edecc28898e8cda1ce15e4087e16e1b9a5d2d7a4d10a2c55398\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).
```

Comment: Basically just follow the basic tutorial for getting a .net web app going in a container an d you  will see it warn with "A non-critical error occurred while getting the container(s) ready. Your project(s) will continue to function normally. The error was: Docker command failed with exit code 125.".  Easy to reproduce, look in container tools on output screen. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 9):

I got this same error when using Windows containers.   However, I switched to Linux containers, and it told me I had to enable volume sharing.  Once that was enabled the sample instructions worked perfectly.

One reason I suspect that Windows containers are not working right now is that in build 1809 of nanoserver the USERNAME was switched from ContainerAdministrator to ContainerUser which has no permissions to write to the root of C: in the docker.

I now have a workaround to enable you to solve the issue you are having while trying to run this sample app using Windows containers.

As Visual Studio 2019 creates your docker file for you when you add docker support (windows), the dockerfile starts off at the top looking like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Change this to the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS base
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN net localgroup administrators /add "User Manager\ContainerUser"
USER ContainerUser
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Note that the 3 lines that I added essentially elevate ContainerUser to admin.

Open a powershell command prompt and do this:

```
docker rmi projname:dev
```

where projname is the name of your project.   This will cause Visual Studio to rebuild from your edited dockerfile.

Under pages shared _Layout.cshtml you can set a breakpoint on the line for @RenderBody().   Set that breakpoint, and press F5 to run with debugging.

You should see the docker rebuild and run successfully, open your browser, and break on that line.   Press F5 again to allow the page to render in the browser.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: By the way, a colleague of mine who was doing this on Windows 10 did not ever experience the issue.   It appears that on her system when she used 2019 to add dockerfile (Windows) support to her project, VS2019 created the docker file to reference the 1803 image instead of the 1809 image.   When I checked out the 1803 image the permissions issue for ContainerUser did not exist.   It had all the needed permissions right from the original pull.   I have not investigated why/when VS2019 makes different decisions for this.  It might be an update to VS 2019 or merely using it on a different OS.

Comment: My original recreation of the error 125 issue was on Windows Server 2019.

Comment: I had an error - access denied and these lines helped me. Great job, thank you!

Comment: On linux containers, I had to allow volume sharing for C and E drives... would check the reasons though, but it works now

Comment: Hi ios, one possible reason might be that Visual Studio does not rebuild the docker container unless you manually delete it.  And if it doesn't rebuild, putting the lines in the docker file does not do anything.  Hence same error.

Comment: What works for me was share the C volumen complete and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, that exception came along with the following message:

```
Error response from daemon: user declined directory sharing C:\Repos\...\src\WorkforceManagementAPI.WEB.
```

I downloaded the latest version of Docker Desktop, which has an explicit list of File Sharing paths (Settings/Resources/File Sharing/add the path: C:\Repos...\src\WorkforceManagementAPI.WEB)

That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem after I added the <DockerfileRunArguments> tag to .csproj file. I had it like this:

```
<DockerfileRunArguments>
   -v "c:/host_path:/container_path"
</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

It was 3 lines and this resulted in Visual Studio 2022 (v17.4) running 'docker run' command with new lines, splitting it. When I moved it to a single line:

```
<DockerfileRunArguments>-v "c:/host_path:/container_path"</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

It started working again :)

After some more "tests" it came out that this tags inner content can't start with a new line, so this is still ok:

```
 <DockerfileRunArguments>-v "c:/host_path:/container_path"
-v "c:/other_host_path:/other_container_path"
</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on wsl2 setting the correct default distro

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
```

This occurred because I created another distro for testing, and on create wsl automatically sets this new distro as default, so docker will run at one distro at time and only on default distro.